# How to use a layer with gradient but without weight adjustment?

Tags: optimization, pytorch, backpropagation

Is it possible to mark part of the forward pass to only backpropagate the gradient but not to adjust weights?

In the following example code I have a `Module` that uses only one layer (one set of parameters) but it is used twice in the forward step. During the optimization I would expect the weights to be adjusted twice as well. If I want to only adjust the weights for one of the layer usages, what can I do?

```py
import torch
    
class ExampleModel(torch.nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, dim) -> None:
        super(ExampleModel, self).__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(dim, dim)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out1 = self.linear(x)  # backprop gradients and adjust weights here
        out2 = self.linear(out1)  # only backprop gradients here
        return out2
    
    
# Random input output data for this example
N, D = 64, 100
x = torch.randn(N, D)
y = torch.randn(N, D)
    
model = ExampleModel(D)
    
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
    
y_pred = model(x)
loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
    
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

The following will not work since with `torch.no_grad()` no gradient at all is backpropagated:

```py
def forward(self, x):
    out1 = self.linear(x)  # backprop gradients and adjust weights here
    with torch.no_grad():
        out2 = self.linear(out1)  # only backprop gradients here
    return out2
```

I can not simply exclude the parameters from the optimization since they need to be optimized in the first part (i.e. `out1 = self.linear(x)`).
For the same reason I can also not set a learning rate of 0 for these parameters.

What else can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to use [requires_grad_](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.requires_grad_) to temporarily disable gradients on the layer's parameters:

```
def forward(self, x):
    out1 = self.linear(x)  # backprop gradients and adjust weights here
    self.linear.requires_grad_(False)
    out2 = self.linear(out1)  # only backprop gradients here
    self.linear.requires_grad_(True)
    return out2
```

This still lets gradients flow through the activations; it merely stops them from reaching the parameters.

You could also consider manipulating the weight tensors manually and calling `.detach()`:

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
def forward(self, x):
    out1 = self.linear(x)
    out2 = F.linear(out1, self.linear.weight.detach(), self.linear.bias.detach())
    return out2
```

Comment: I had also asked this question on the pytorch forum and ptrblck added explanations to your suggestions: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-use-a-layer-with-gradient-but-without-weight-adjustment/86190/4

Comment: Great, I fleshed out the answer a bit